# Echo data from array

Tags: php, html, twitter

I am currently calling Twitter's "Trending" API with PHP and I want to return the top 10 trending topics. Currently it appears to be echoed into an array but I can't work out how to get an individual piece of data on it's one.

I want to just return the `name` attribute for each one. How can I do this?

My existing code is:

```
<?

$search=file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json");
print_r(json_decode($search));

?>
```

Decoded array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [trends] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #EuroclubSoloEnEuropaFM
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23EuroclubSoloEnEuropaFM
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23EuroclubSoloEnEuropaFM
                            [events] => 
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [name] => #NBABands
                            [url] => http://twitter.com/search?q=%23NBABands
                            [promoted_content] => 
                            [query] => %23NBABands
                            [events] => 
                        )
                       //...
```

Comment: After further investigation, I noticed the array contains objects. You should supply a clip of the array in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume that `json_decode` returns an associative array. You could get the value of the name by doing this:

```
<?

$search=file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/trends/1.json");
$trends = json_decode($search);
foreach ($trends[0]->trends as $trend){
    echo $trend->name . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you post what the page says when you execute `echo var_dump($trends);`?

Comment: Ok, I added an edit that _should_ fix the problem.

Comment: It's better if you actually removed the faulty code and replaced it with the correct code instead of moving it under an EDIT-title.

Comment: @user2027056 I think that fixed it. I left off the [0].

Comment: @user2027056 By the looks of things (at the link you provided), you got it all sorted out. Good luck with your project!